# ZF2 Localization Translator

Tags: localization, zend-framework2, language-translation

I'm following the method for translation specified here:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.i18n.translating.html#setting-a-locale

Because most of my strings already existed in a DB and I didn't want to transfer them to POEdit, I'm generating a bunch of PHP Array files like en_US.php, de_DE.php, etc.

In module/Application/config/module.config.php the pattern is defined as:

```
        array(
            'type'     => 'phparray',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.php',
        ),
```

Setting the translator like this in module/Applicaation/Module.php:

```
   public function onBootstrap($e)
   {
    // ...snip...

   $sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
   $sm->get('translator')
       ->setLocale(\Locale::acceptFromHttp($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']))
       ->setFallbackLocale('en_US');

    // ...snip...
```

}

And performing tranlations in the view like:

```
<th><?= $this->translate('Date Created'); ?></th>
```

Everything works except...Traditional and Simplified Chinese. If I'm reading the docs correctly zh_CN.php should be picked up for users with Simplified Chinese as their setting, and zh_HK should be picked up for users with Traditional Chinese. But it's not working. It only picks up zh.php and I lose my variations.

I'm on a Mac, so to test, I'm just changing my system preferences and relaunching my browser. All of my western languages (en_US.php, fr_FR.php, it_IT.php, nl_NL.php, etc) work as expected. But, for Japanese, I had to name my file ja.php, and I can't get Chinese to accommodate the different country codes.

Any ideas? How do I rule out if the problem is in my naming convention, an additional setting (is my pattern wrong) or do I need to pass more params when I call translate?

MORE INVESTIGATION
 Looking at what is being returned from the headers there is a difference:

```
 $locale = locale_accept_from_http($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
 var_dump($locale);
```

will print string(2) "zh" zh

```
var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
```

will print string(5) "zh-tw"

So perhaps I should be using the below, but it's absolutely not what's specified in the docs

```
        ->setLocale($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using `Locale::acceptFromHttp()`? You can write your own parser easily with the ZF2 request object.

```
$headers = $request->getHeaders();
if ($headers->has('Accept-Language')) {
    $locales = $headers->get('Accept-Language')->getPrioritized();
    $first   = array_shift($locales);

    // "language" here is the full locale, though it's quite confusing :s
    return $first->getLanguage();
}
```

There are others complaining about the magic of `acceptFromHttp()` and the apparent bugs in this part.

Mind that checking this code (as well as using `acceptFromHttp()` does not look for backup alternatives. Let's say your application defaults to 'fr-FR' and you support 'fr-FR' and 'en-US'. A client makes a request with Accept-Language 'nl-NL' and 'en-US'. Your code will check 'nl-NL', which is not supported, and uses the fallback 'fr-FR'. However, the second best option from the client ('en-US') is supported in your app. So you're sending back a locale which the client cannot understand, while you have in fact a negotiable locale available.

NB. You can use [SlmLocale](http://github.com/juriansluiman/SlmLocale) for ZF2 to detect locales automatically with a fallback and locale negotiation. The locale is set into php's Locale object with `setDefault()` so translators and the like pick up this locale automatically. *Disclaimer I wrote that library :)*

Comment: +1 for explanation about the `acceptFromHttp()` part. Another Module to take into consideration i assume ;)

Comment: This was a perfect answer! Thank you for the information. The additional module is more than I need as we only have a very specific number of translations available so falling back to English is going to be ok. I'm not expecting someone who's first choice is Simplified Chinese to than want Dutch as the next option. The languages we are supporting don't have a lot of variants, except Chinese.

Comment: Oh, and to your first question, ->setLocale(\Locale::acceptFromHttp($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])), is how it's written up in the example docs, which is what I was referencing. It works until you get to regional variants.

Comment: My browser send's nl not nl_NL so this does not work for 2 char languages.